# Как выводить данные по определенной дате?

Tags: php, mysql

В файле есть вот такой код, где я с помощью Datepicker выбираю дату:

```
Ежедневный отчет за:  <input type="text" class="from_date select_date" value="<? echo $date = date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
```

Здесь вывожу таблицу из бд:

```
<?php
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM income_expense_history ");

    //$result - ассоциированный массив, т.е. таблички, у которой есть названия столбцов

    //узнаем, сколько в массиве $result строчек
    $n=mysql_num_rows($result);

    //вывод на страничку в виде таблицы
    echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 style=width: 75% align=center>
<tr>
    <th>Время</th>
    <th>Приход</th>
    <th>Расход</th>
    <th>Комментарий</th>
    <th>Автор</th>
</tr>";

    //вывод построчно
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
        echo
        "</td><td>",mysql_result($result,$i,time),
        "</td><td>",mysql_result($result,$i,income),
        "</td><td>",mysql_result($result,$i,expense),
        "</td><td>",mysql_result($result,$i,comment),
        "</td><td>",mysql_result($result,$i, author),
        "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

Как связать их вместе? Чтобы когда я выбирал определенную дату, из базы брались данные за выбранный день? В базе хранятся в timestamp, по умолчанию current_timestamp. Спасибо

Comment: "SELECT * FROM income_expense_history WHERE ДАТА=ВЫБРАННЫЙ_ДЕНЬ"?

Comment: @ Skrillexazem - Такой вариант не срабатывает. Мне нужно чтобы я выбирал дату, я её сделал datepicker, но при выборе даты значения не возвращаются, приходит пустое

Comment: Можете код скинуть, как вы делали?

Comment: @ Skrillexazem -Здравствуйте. Вопрос уже решился. Вот пример, проблема была в переводе из таймстап: $data = $_GET["date"];
  if(isset($data)) {
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `income_expense_history` WHERE DATE(`time`) = \"$data\" ");
                    }else{
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM income_expense_history  WHERE DATE(`time`) = \"$date\"");
                    }

Comment: Здорово что решился, но пожалуйста, почитайте про более новые драйвера для работы с БД. Такие как PDO и MySQLi.